# Stripe - Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

Tags: stripe-payments

I have the follow block of PHP code which generates a new Stripe customer using a token, since i don't want to handle the card details on my server

```
$stripe_customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        'source' => $token,
        'description' => $displayname,
        'metadata' => array('BHAA_ID'=>$bhaa_id),
        'email' => $email
    )
);
$stripe_customer_id=$stripe_customer->id;
```

I then attempt to register the card with these calls

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($stripe_customer_id);
$card = $customer->sources->create(array("source" => $token));
```

The final step is to then charge the created customer like this using the customer id

```
// https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#create_charge
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'amount' => $amount*100,
    'currency' => 'eur',
    'customer' => $stripe_customer->id,
    'description' => $booking_description,
    'metadata' => array("booking_id" => $booking_id, "event_name" => $booking_description),
    'statement_descriptor' => "abc",
    'receipt_email' => get_userdata($user_id)->user_email
));
```

This was working, but i recently updated to the 3.5.0 version of the stripe PHP API. I'm now getting this error

```
Booking could not be created:
Connection error:: "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card"
```

From what i can make out, it now seems that I have to register a card with the customer but I can't find any examples of this.

Any advise would be appreciated.

EDIT - Add stripe dashboard details

From the stripe dashboard, I can see that my customer is registered. This is in the response log

```
id: cus_7Xq5jNrrLfv73U
object: "customer"
account_balance: 0
created: 1450292050
currency: null
default_source: null
delinquent: false
description: "Web Master"
```

This is a screen shot of the 'Register Card' request. I can see that the 'customer id' is present in the URL, but the source parameter is not present as a Query Parameter or in the post body.

[image]

Comment: If you go to your Stripe Dashboard and go to logs do you see the token being provided when you create the customer? My initial guess is that $token is null / undefined / or an empty string.

Comment: @MatthewArkin I thought the same initially, but my customer is getting created so I believe the token value is correctly defined. Please see the extra stripe dashboard details I've added to the question.

Comment: Hi there @emeraldjava Did you ever resolve this issue? I am having the same problem, however I am using the Node.js set up